# How to get rows between two hours from a datetime column?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have a `datetime` column. How can I get the rows in which the `Date` column is between two specific hours (regardless of day, month, and year).

For example, any row whose hour is between `14:00:00` and `15:00:00` (for all days)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select * from table where hour(datetime) between 14 and 16
```

or

`select * from table where time(datetime) between '14:00:00' and '16:00:00`'

Answer (score 3):

You can use `time()` or `hour()`:

```
where hour(datetime) >= 14 and hour(datetime) < 16
```

or:

```
where time(datetime) >= '14:00:00' and time(datetime) < '16:00:00'
```

or you might prefer this as:

```
where time(datetime) >= '14:00:00' and
      time(datetime) < '15:00:00' + interval 1 hour
```

Note: None of these will use an index because of the function call on the `datetime` column.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
 from (
  select cast (substr(to_char(datetime,'YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS'),12,2) as integer ) as compare 
      from table )
where compare between 14 and 15;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Comment: 1)to_char(datetime,'YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS')  => this convert your date in string
2)substr(to_char(datetime,'YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS'),12,2) => this substr function selects the string that are specified i.e start and end part of that string.
3)cast (substr(to_char(datetime,'YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS'),12,2) as integer ) => then convert selected string converted as integer then you can compare this integer number .

Comment: Please add all explanation to the answer, not to the comment section